# How to specify local machine when already sshed into another computer?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp

It's easy to simply scp from another computer to the local one or vice versa. However, how to do it when you already sshed into another computer?

```
user@anothercomp:~/$ssh ~/path/file (how to specify local computer?):~/localpath/file
```

Note that my computer is a personal laptop instead of a server, so answers here [Download files to local drive when sshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/download-files-to-local-drive-when-sshed) do not apply since it requires to specify the domain name, and my laptop is no server.

So what's the correct way to specify my local computer? (Please don't say exit ssh and then scp, since it will possibly lose temporary data when working)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, when you are SSH'd into another machine, your terminal is then a virtual "extension" of that machine and cannot access your local file system.  You could attempt a ssh loopback and have the machine you are ssh'd into ssh back to your local machine, though this would require you to have openssh installed.  I may be wrong, but I am pretty sure you cannot access your machine from the same shell you are using to ssh into another machine ..

Comment: This is all possible with port-forwarding, but you need to clarify exactly what you want to do. Call your laptop `A` and two remote systems `B` and `C`.  Explain exactly how you are connected and where you want to copy files from and to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to exit ssh, you can run scp from another virtual terminal in your laptop.

For convenience, you may want to try connection sharing, to avoid the need to enter passwords again; you may either use ssh -M or modify ~/.ssh/config. See man ssh and man ssh_config for details.

Answer (score 0):

By SSH'ing into the second machine you lose the context of your first.  For the purpose of transferring files the second machine would need to `scp` the files to the first, or could use a different (yet similar) approach such as `sshfs`.

If the issue is that the second machine does not have network access to the first, then tunneling is the likely solution.  However, this just enabled scp or sshfs to connect--it doesn't let your ssh session access paths or variables from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

While your computer does not have a domain name, it still has an IP address, so you can connect to the IP address. You can retrieve the address from the `SSH_CLIENT` variable. See [How to get the IP address from $SSH_CLIENT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2230478/850848).

Obviously to ssh or scp to your computer, you need to be running an SSH server there. What is not common, if you are running Windows, in particular.